.htaccess is giving me error of page no found
I'm trying to change this url /article.php?title=blog+name&id=1 to /article/blog+name/1
my code is this
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z.]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z.]+) /article.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

thank you very much in advance

Your RewriteRule pattern for title contains only the characters 0-9a-zA-Z. , but your example has +, so it doesn't match. If you use /article/blog.name/1 it should work. You may also want to restrict the id pattern to [0-9]+ if it's just going to be an integer.

Inevitably patterns like this compound, so you have this rule for articles, and then another for news, another for blogs, and so on. Although not right or wrong, I really encourage people to look at just switching to a single router script via FallbackResource or catch-all RewriteRule. This gives you full access to PHP where you can use parse_url, explode, str_starts_with, etc., and have more descriptive logic than just RegEx. You can also write tests and have platform independence as an added benefit. Just my two cents.

Putting complex, app-specific config into the app itself also makes your app more portable. Eg: if you switch to nginx you won't have to re-do all of the regular expressions in nginx's syntax. [.htaccess is an apache-only thing]

That probably is what you are looking for:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?article/([0-9a-z\s.+]+)/(\d+)$ /article.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

This allows for whitespaces, dots (".") and plus characters ("+") in the title, is insensitive to character case and rewrites as expected. Have a try yourself with a tester.
But pay attention to the suggestions you received in the comments about a different routing strategy: to rewrite all requests to a single routing script. In that you then have the full potential of php to parse, interpret and handle the requests. That would simply be something like that:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [NC,L]


Just to be clear, when you say all do you mean it literally, including static assets? As much as I'm an advocate for using a router, unless there's a specific need for performing server-side logic on things like binary data (advanced permissions, content type negotiation, etc.), I think I'd still prefer to let the server handle that. That's why I like FallbackResource in htaccess. Whatever the server can't figure out on its own, pass it over to PHP to try.

@ChrisHaas Well, it depends, I'd say ... Sure, if you have lots of static stuff, then that might make sense. But then again there are solutions where you have next to no such static resources. And there are also situations where you do not want to deliver static resources without access control, static does not mean non personal ... So the bottom line to me is: think about it, make a decision, implement that.

In case such static assets should be excluded from such a general strategy one can simple implement an exception rule for those (for example based on a static path prefix /static/ or similar. Such rule has to be implemented before the general catch-all route rewriting to the routing script, so further up in the configuration file.
